# Aggregating to String and Summing the Values Associated to Aggregate in R 3.3.0 Dplyr v 0.5.0

Tags: r, dplyr

Question:

**I have the following data frame** that I want to simplify

```
Fruit <-  c("Apple","Apple","Orange","Orange","Banana","Banana")
Farmer <- c("Bob","Ben","Bill","Bob","George","Bob")
Tons.Jan <- c(20,40,10,20,35,15)
Tons.Feb <- c(30,40,20,15,25,30)
Tons.Mar <- c(10,10,15,10,20,30)
Tons.Apr <- c(15,20,15,30,30,30)
Tons.May <- c(20,5,20,20,20,10)

df <- cbind(Fruit,Farmer)
df <- cbind(df,Tons.Jan)
df <- cbind(df,Tons.Feb)
df <- cbind(df,Tons.Mar)
df <- cbind(df,Tons.Apr)
df <- tbl_df(cbind(df,Tons.May))
```

I want to be able to summarise the Farmers to a single comma delimited strong and sum the Tons to the observations so that it looks like the following

**I want to get to the following**

```
Fruit2 <- c("Apple","Orange","Banana")
Farmer2 <- c("Bob,Ben","Bill,Bob","George,Bob")
Tons.Jan2 <- c(60,30,50)
Tons.Feb2 <- c(70,35,55)
Tons.Mar2 <- c(20,25,50)
Tons.Apr2 <- c(35,45,60)
Tons.May2 <- c(25,40,30)

df2 <- cbind(Fruit2,Farmer2)
df2 <- cbind(df2,Tons.Jan2)
df2 <- cbind(df2,Tons.Feb2)
df2 <- cbind(df2,Tons.Mar2)
df2 <- cbind(df2,Tons.Apr2)
df2 <- tbl_df(cbind(df2,Tons.May2))
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried using dplyr function group_by and summarise_each below

```
df <- df %>% group_by(Fruit) %>%
   summarise_each_(funs(toString))
```

However I am not sure how to integrate summing the numeric values without specifically calling out each column using the summarise function,

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# Convert the relevant columns to numeric
df <- mutate_each(df, funs(as.numeric), -Fruit, -Farmer)

# or as mentioned in the comments by jazzurro
df <- mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with("Tons")), as.numeric)

df %>% 
    group_by(Fruit) %>% 
    mutate(Farmer = toString(Farmer)) %>%
    group_by(Fruit, Farmer) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum))


#Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
#Groups: Fruit [?]
#
#   Fruit      Farmer Tons.Jan Tons.Feb Tons.Mar Tons.Apr Tons.May
#   <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  Apple    Bob, Ben       60       70       20       35       25
#2 Banana George, Bob       50       55       50       60       30
#3 Orange   Bill, Bob       30       35       25       45       40
```

Comment: I think you can overwrite Farmer by `mutate(Farmer = toString(Farmer))`. The last step can be written as `summarize_each(funs(sum(.)))` at the moment. In the future, summarize_each seems to be deprecated. So I think using summarize_all is a good thing to do. One more thing. In order to convert character to numeric, you can use `mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with("Tons")), as.numeric)` too.

Comment: Yeah was about to overwrite Farmer! Thanks!

Comment: This works! I used jazzurro's suggestion to overwrite the Farmer variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is better not to do the `data.frame(cbind(` or `tbl_df(cbind` as the `cbind` binds the `vector`s to a `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class, so while we change `matrix` to `data.frame` (with the default option i.e. `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`), if there are **any**  character `vector`, the `matrix` will be all `character` class columns and this gets worsened as the columns are now `factor` class with `data.frame` conversion.   So, we unnecessarily have to do `as.numeric(as.character(` for changing the `type` of `numeric` columns.  It is better to construct the 'data.frame' as

```
data.frame(Fruit, Farmer, Tons.Jan, ...)
```

---

A `data.table` solution would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  Farmer :=  toString(Farmer), by = Fruit][ , 
     lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(as.numeric(as.character(x)))) , .(Fruit, Farmer)]
#    Fruit                   Farmer Tons.Jan Tons.Feb Tons.Mar Tons.Apr Tons.May
#1:  Apple       Bob, Ben, Bob, Ben       60       70       20       35       25
#2: Orange     Bill, Bob, Bill, Bob       30       35       25       45       40
#3: Banana George, Bob, George, Bob       50       55       50       60       30
```

Also, this can be done in a single step with grouping by 'Fruit' (based on the OP's output)

```
setDT(df)[, c(Farmer = toString(Farmer), lapply(.SD[, 
   setdiff(names(.SD), "Farmer"), with = FALSE], 
       function(x) sum(as.numeric(as.character(x))))), .(Fruit)]
#    Fruit      Farmer Tons.Jan Tons.Feb Tons.Mar Tons.Apr Tons.May
#1:  Apple    Bob, Ben       60       70       20       35       25
#2: Orange   Bill, Bob       30       35       25       45       40
#3: Banana George, Bob       50       55       50       60       30
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll use this going forward.